# I have a connection to LDAP with java code, i want to extract it in properties file or xml file in order to solve transportation issues

Tags: java, xml, properties, ldap

Well this my java code that allows me to connect to the ldap server.

```
  public static Hashtable getConnexion()
           {

       env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
       env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389");
       env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
       env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=admin,ou=system"); 
       env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
       return env;

       }
```

thanks

Comment: And your question is? and the meaning of "extract it in properties file or xml file in order to solve transportation issues" is? What "transportation issues" for example? Not a real question.

Comment: i meant.. when dealing with transport certainly when the application is on a professional way.. the connection must be configured outside the java code..that's why i think with an xml file or properties, this can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the LDAP client is standalone, it could be configured in several ways:

Use the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/) `LDAPCommandLineTool` class and specify arguments to the program. For example, if the name of the class containing the `main` method was `samplecode.MyLdapConnectionClass`:

```
java -cp my-classpath samplecode.MyLdapConnectionClass --hostname localhost \
       --port 10389 \
       --bindDN "uid=admin,ou=system" \
       --bindPassword "secret"
```

The UnboundID LDAP SDK `LDAPCommandLineTool` class handles all these types of command line arguments automatically, for example:

- `--hostname` (or `-h`) for the hostname
- `--port` (or `-p`) for the port
- all SASL and Simple BIND arguments
- all secure connection arguments, for example (`--useSSL` or `--useStartTLS`)

The `LDAPCommandLineTool` class inherits a method `getConnection()` which establishes a connection to the server specified by those command line arguments.

or specify the name of a properties file and parse the properties file using Apache Commons Configuration or the `load()` method of `java.util.properties`.

Either way, JNDI should not be used for new code. Use the UnboundID LDAP SDK instead.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Sample Code](https://code.google.com/p/ldap-sample-code)
- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

One more option. You can put the above properties as JVM properties.

Comment: java -DLdapCtxFactory= "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
  -DPROVIDER_URL="ldap://localhost:10389"
  
Add all as the System properties (sorry not JVM properties) 
 
and in the code
 
  env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            Ssytem.getProperty("LdapCtxFactory"));
   
if it is an independent application.
   
If it is running inside web application server we can set as System (Server VM) properties. You need to go thru the documentation of th server  how to to set this.

Comment: @aminelazio Ignore this clumsy technique. A far better option is to put it all in /jndi.properties in the JAR file.